# is there a simply way through which i can filter json data based on different conditions

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, filter

I am getting the following data as a response from one of my web service. I want to filter the data based on several combinations of different value. what will be the simplest way to do it so that it does affect the performance of my web service

Data : I am Getting array of objects

```
[
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000366563",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "42",
            "coexpression3": "42",
            "experimental": "174",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "298",
            "combinedscore4": "298",
            "experimental2": "174",
            "combinedscore": "298",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "298",
            "experimental3": "174",
            "experimental4": "174",
            "coexpression4": "42",
            "textmining3": "184",
            "coexpression": "42",
            "textmining4": "184",
            "textmining2": "184",
            "textmining": "184"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000402551",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "148",
            "coexpression3": "148",
            "experimental": "138",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "247",
            "combinedscore4": "247",
            "experimental2": "138",
            "combinedscore": "247",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "247",
            "experimental3": "138",
            "experimental4": "138",
            "coexpression4": "148",
            "textmining3": "57",
            "coexpression": "148",
            "textmining4": "57",
            "textmining2": "57",
            "textmining": "57"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000386239",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "49",
            "coexpression3": "49",
            "experimental": "120",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "190",
            "combinedscore4": "190",
            "experimental2": "120",
            "combinedscore": "190",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "190",
            "experimental3": "120",
            "experimental4": "120",
            "coexpression4": "49",
            "textmining3": "110",
            "coexpression": "49",
            "textmining4": "110",
            "textmining2": "110",
            "textmining": "110"
        }
    }
]
```

conditions: `where textmining >/</= 100 and coexpression >/</= 30 and combinedscore >/</= 250`
the data has to be filtered based on 5 filter values(textmining,coexpression,experimental, database and combinedscore) with greaterthan/ equal to / less than condition and all this has to be used input.

Comment: Please be more specific.  What are you filtering on? Give some examples if input and output.

Comment: Whats the condition? be more  clear. What does >/// mean?

Comment: That's an array of objects.  You can use [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to do what you want.

Comment: Those are not objects btw, it's JSON @Archer

Comment: @Kevin.a JSON is a text format. Once you get the data from wherever, it's an array of objects.

Comment: I thought you had to parse it first in order to work with it? @HereticMonkey

Comment: Sure, but the question is unclear about how they are receiving the JSON. If they are simply `import`ing it, it would already be parsed.

Comment: Yeah, i just thought it was worth mentioning it. He wants to compare numbers, but JSON is all strings. Strict comparison wont work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*It does depends on what `specific` logic you want to `execute` on array.*
 but generally getting values and for comparing values  i think better option would be loops.

**Performance wise**

see [more detail here](https://hackernoon.com/javascript-performance-test-for-vs-for-each-vs-map-reduce-filter-find-32c1113f19d7)

[image: performance analysis of for loop]

Answer (score 1):

```js
const arr = [
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000366563",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "42",
            "coexpression3": "42",
            "experimental": "174",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "298",
            "combinedscore4": "298",
            "experimental2": "174",
            "combinedscore": "298",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "298",
            "experimental3": "174",
            "experimental4": "174",
            "coexpression4": "42",
            "textmining3": "184",
            "coexpression": "42",
            "textmining4": "184",
            "textmining2": "184",
            "textmining": "184"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000402551",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "148",
            "coexpression3": "148",
            "experimental": "138",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "247",
            "combinedscore4": "247",
            "experimental2": "138",
            "combinedscore": "247",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "247",
            "experimental3": "138",
            "experimental4": "138",
            "coexpression4": "148",
            "textmining3": "57",
            "coexpression": "148",
            "textmining4": "57",
            "textmining2": "57",
            "textmining": "57"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000386239",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "49",
            "coexpression3": "49",
            "experimental": "120",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "190",
            "combinedscore4": "190",
            "experimental2": "120",
            "combinedscore": "190",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "190",
            "experimental3": "120",
            "experimental4": "120",
            "coexpression4": "49",
            "textmining3": "110",
            "coexpression": "49",
            "textmining4": "110",
            "textmining2": "110",
            "textmining": "110"
        }
    }
] ; 

console.log(arr.filter(entry => entry.relationshipdetails.textmining > 110 ))
```

Use filter. In my example i am filtering everything smaller than 110. using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) You can apply it to the rest using the example i gave

Ideally you'd store these results into a variable. For the sake of the explanation I am simply logging it.

Comment: anything i can explain better?

Answer (score 1):

You can use filter and just add your required comparison and logical to return true or false

```js
var data = [
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000366563",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "42",
            "coexpression3": "42",
            "experimental": "174",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "298",
            "combinedscore4": "298",
            "experimental2": "174",
            "combinedscore": "298",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "298",
            "experimental3": "174",
            "experimental4": "174",
            "coexpression4": "42",
            "textmining3": "184",
            "coexpression": "42",
            "textmining4": "184",
            "textmining2": "184",
            "textmining": "184"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000402551",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "148",
            "coexpression3": "148",
            "experimental": "138",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "247",
            "combinedscore4": "247",
            "experimental2": "138",
            "combinedscore": "247",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "247",
            "experimental3": "138",
            "experimental4": "138",
            "coexpression4": "148",
            "textmining3": "57",
            "coexpression": "148",
            "textmining4": "57",
            "textmining2": "57",
            "textmining": "57"
        }
    },
    {
        "source": "9606.ENSP00000000233",
        "target": "9606.ENSP00000386239",
        "relationship": "ON_INTERACTION_WITH",
        "relationshipdetails": {
            "database4": "0",
            "database3": "0",
            "coexpression2": "49",
            "coexpression3": "49",
            "experimental": "120",
            "database2": "0",
            "combinedscore3": "190",
            "combinedscore4": "190",
            "experimental2": "120",
            "combinedscore": "190",
            "database": "0",
            "combinedscore2": "190",
            "experimental3": "120",
            "experimental4": "120",
            "coexpression4": "49",
            "textmining3": "110",
            "coexpression": "49",
            "textmining4": "110",
            "textmining2": "110",
            "textmining": "110"
        }
    }
]

var filtered = data.filter((entry) => {
  if (!('relationshipdetails' in entry)) return false
  return (entry.relationshipdetails.textmining > 100 && entry.relationshipdetails.coexpression < 50)
});

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the input object `input` and the conditions `textmining > 100` and `coexpression < 30`:

`var result = input
    .filter (entry => entry ["relationshipdetails"] ["textmining"] > 100)
    .filter (entry => entry ["relationshipdetails"] ["coexpression"] < 30); // etc...`

(See [the MDN docs on `Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).)